# Where is the unicorn-unicoins land?

Tags: discussion, community, unicoins, unicorns

Really want to go there, seems to be quite interesting place.

Please give me directions or show me on the map.

Comment: Could you ask a more practical question.

Comment: Well unicorn theme is very practical... I think it is been initiated by the idea itself

Comment: Asking directions however is not practical.

Answer (score 4):

Go to OZ and follow the rainbow brick road, not the yellow brick road that will take you some place else.

Comment: wooooo apparently there is a unicorn mafia who don't like when people talk about unicorn business shh....

Comment: Note: I didn't tell him not to eat the food when he gets there :)

Answer (score 3):

Same directions as getting to never-never-land, only it is the **third** star to the right.

Comment: I bet you can see it with a naked eye if the skies are clear